# Error on Ionic build Android?

Tags: ionic-framework

i am working on a ionic application. I am getting an error while trying to build for android.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Can you please check whether you have installed "java" and also enough space available on your drive?

Comment: I have installed Android Studio and JRE, what else we need for that

Comment: As per my knowledge there is no need of  Android Studio for ionic app we just need android sdk.

Comment: okay! that is installed already

Answer (score 0):

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

From the message, seems it is caused by the JVM heap space when build the ionic project with gradle, please try to increase heap size in Java

The simple steps for windows system:

1. Config the GRADLE_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS in your local environment with following parameters

   -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

(If you are using JDK8, the PermSize will be ignored.)

Ref
[Configuring the build environment](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)

Comment: i am using windows. could you please update your answer with steps

Comment: trying this solution

Comment: @RaviMittal How many memory of your PC? Then you can try to add more like `-Xmx1024m`

Comment: updated to this
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

but same error. Do i need to restart my machine

Comment: @RaviMittal I'm not sure where you set the local environment, you can open the GRADLE_HOME\bin\gradle.bat with any notepad, then you will find a link `set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=`, you can put the jvm arguments here. Or you can add `set JAVA_OPTS=` in the top of the gradle.bat.